# Is it actually safe for battery health to keep power adapter plugged if MacBook is charged (Mac OS10.15.5 )?

Tags: macbook-pro, catalina, battery, charging

Sometimes I do small gaming on my MacBook Pro and it discharges quite quickly while running games. I understand that this is normal for every laptop. But in the latest update 10.15.5, there is a "Battery Health management feature" but there is no description of what exactly it does.

So, my question is Is it safe to keep MacBook plugged while it is charged?

This question in my case is applicable for gaming and other heavy programs (Video editing, etc).

Comment: Apple describes Battery Heath Management here: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT211094 This Venturebeat column lists (at the bottom) the Apple laptops which support it: https://venturebeat.com/2020/04/16/macos-10-15-5-improves-macbook-charging-with-battery-health-management/

Comment: The actual use of the device doesn't change chemistry or physics.  If it needs to be charged, battery management will handle it.  When it's full, the battery management will handle that as well.